# Do posts that got anonymized after I delete my account, get de-anonymized if I sign up on that site again?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Say my StackOverflow account is deleted due my demand through Contact Us page.

The questions and answers I have posted are now anonymized (they are posted by userxxxxxxx)

What happens if I sign up on StackOverflow with the same StackExchange account? Do questions get de-anonymized and get credited to me again instead of userxxxxxxx? Or do they stay as they anonymized?

Answer (score 13):

The posts remain anonymised - that is why the warning for when the deletion option on the Contact Us page states that:

> **User deletion is irreversible!** We're sorry to see you go. Your reputation and votes will be removed and all of your content will be made anonymous.

(emphasis mine).

You could contact the team again to ask to have the posts reassociated, but I would imagine that this request would be very unlikely to be successful, unless in a specific set of circumstances as stated by @animuson below:

> We don't reattach old questions to a new profile unless the deletion was our error.

Comment: We don't reattach old questions to a new profile unless the deletion was our error.

Comment: @animuson I thought that would be the case - thank you for clarifying that